# Why is AutoMapper failing due to mappings in unrelated models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I've inherited an MVC 3 project that uses AutoMapper. It appears to use nothing but the default Automapper configuration (I can't find any other configuration for Automapper anywhere in the solution, in other words). So I've written code like this for two new models I've added to the project:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entities.Document, Models.Attachment>();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
return Mapper.Map <List<Entities.Document>, List<Models.Attachment>>(Attachments);
```

Which ought to work fine - but the problem is that Automapper fails because of an inability to map completely unrelated objects. In other words, I get this message when Mapper.Map is called:

```
The following 2 properties on MyApp.Models.User are not mapped: 
    IsAdminUser
    SubRoleList
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, or rename the property on       
MyApp.Entities.UserProfile.
```

Why is the mapping failing when Models.User has nothing to do with the models I'm mapping? They don't inherit from it. They don't contain any references to it. My new models are very simple models that contain a few strings and ints. MyApp.Models.User doesn't rely on them for anything, either.

I realize this problem can be solved by specifying the mappings in my AutoMapper calls. In fact, I've already done so, and it solves the problem. So I'm not worried about that. I can move on. What I'm worried about is that I can't figure out for the life of me why I'm getting this message when I try to use the default mapping. There are many other objects in the app which are very similar to the new objects I'm trying to map. They all work perfectly when code like the above is called. They don't require specifying any mappings and they don't have problems with MyApp.Models.User. I just want to know WHY this is happening because I want to understand it. Anyone got ideas? In case it's not obvious, I'm relatively new to MVC and Automapper. Thanks. :)

EDIT: Additional information:

If I add a call to Mapper.Reset() before the call to CreateMap(), everything works perfectly. I still don't understand why my method is the only method in the app that needs a Reset first.

Comment: The Mapper.CreateMap method should be called only once for the entire lifetime of the application. Ideally inside `Application_Start`. Why are you redefining your mappings everytime before you map?

Comment: Only because that's the way it's done throughout the application I've inherited. What I would really like to understand is why this logic works everywhere else, but not when I try it. Down the road I could consider re-architecting all of this, but that's outside the scope of what I'm working on at the moment.

Comment: Well the reason for this error could be because you might have concurrent requests each of them constantly modifying the mapping rules which is not the way AutoMapper was intended to be used. You define the mapping rules once, and you use the Map method many times.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I see what you are saying, but I'm the only person using the app, and in debug mode at that, stepping carefully through the code. I don't think there are any other requests going on. And it's not so much a question of 'Is this right?' so much as 'Why does it work everywhere else and not here?'. I want to understand that.